# EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS Crash in our app

Tags: ios, objective-c, exc-bad-access

We are facing a crash in our app but we are not able to get the exact area of the crash.
I am attaching the crash report for the reference.

```
Crashed: Thread
0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x2470 objc_release + 16
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x65c8 AutoreleasePoolPage::releaseUntil(objc_object**) + 196
2  libobjc.A.dylib                0x2e30 objc_autoreleasePoolPop + 204
3  libobjc.A.dylib                0x4b40 AutoreleasePoolPage::tls_dealloc(void*) + 132
4  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x6e10 _pthread_tsd_cleanup + 520
5  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x9c88 _pthread_exit + 80
6  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x8120 pthread_exit + 56
7  Foundation                     0xa688 -[NSThread main] + 14
8  Foundation                     0x638c0 __NSThread__start__ + 812
9  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x63a4 _pthread_start + 116
10 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x49fc thread_start + 8
```

Comment: Did you set the Exception Breakpoint?

Comment: Yes we have already tried setting Exception Breakpoint.